# reactiveui samples

Tags: windows-phone-7, winrt-xaml, reactiveui

I'm really amazed with reactive extensions library created by Microsoft and the MVVM framework 'reactiveui' build on top of it. I would love to use it in my project, but I cannot find any examples of using it in standard applications. I've seen Paul's (creator) blog posts, but what I need is not samples of codes, but sample application.

I want to build windows phone7/ windows 8 application with Reactive-UI, but I would like to know how to exactly use it in the there (not dry 3lines of usage example).

Please let me know if you know any open source examples, where Reactive-UI has been used.

Comment: Why is this not constructive? It's asking for a concrete answer (URLs for sample applications).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/reactiveui/reactiveui)

In the  **ReactiveUI.Sample.WP7** folder you can find the Sample application.

Comment: Great, but do you know any Windows 8 examples as well? Or other sample project from different repositories?

Comment: https://github.com/reactiveui/reactiveui.samples is a better place for samples, and http://github.com/play/play-windows, http://github.com/xpaulbettsx/akavacheexplorer, and http://github.com/play/play-win8 are examples of full applications